# Windows Command Prompt(cmd) move command

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt, move, cd

Moving files in windows command prompt using the "move" command.

```
C:\>move c:\OEM\lol.txt c:\Programdata\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\lol.jpg
```

For some reason this won't move the file to the desired location. Could someone help me with the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get into the habit of double quoting your paths and filenames and it should be fine.

```
move "c:\OEM\lol.txt" "c:\Programdata\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\lol.jpg"
```

The space is the issue there, and the quotes protect it.